# Linkedlist en python. Tomando como valor un array

Tags: python, github

Recibí un planteo en una entrevista que me dejó intrigado sobre su desarrollo. Se requiere que una clase Linkedlist reciba como parametro inicial una lista. y cada item de lista se va convirtiendo en nodo. siendo el primer nodo el Head.
Había que escribir el codigo para las funciones de inserción de cada item en la linkedlist y una función que obtenía y devolvía el ultimo ítem de la linkedlist.
y una última función que printeaba la linkedlist pero en formato de lista.
Me quemé mucho la cabeza pensando pero creo que iba por buen camino pero sin embargo el Visual Studio Code no se si se bugeó o que, pero me reclamaba una mal indentación por ciertos campos del código.

Quiero que alguien experimentado le eche un vistazo y me diga que tal lo vé.
mi codigo está en mi perfil publico de github. paso link!

https://github.com/arielgv/TestLinkedList

```py
def reversed_list( nodes ) :
    ############# DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW #############
    my_ll = MySpecialList(nodes)
    head = my_ll.root
    reversed_head = my_ll.reverseList(head)
    return my_ll.print_as_list(reversed_head)
    ############# DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE #############



class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = data
        self.next = None



class MySpecialList:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        # Given an array, initialize it into a Linked List
        # The head of the Linked List should be saved as self.head
        
        self.arr = arr
        self.head = None
        for item in arr:
            self.insert(Node(item))
            


    def insert(self, root, item):
    # Given the root/head of a Linked List, appened the item to the end of the Linked List
    # Function should return the root/head of the Linked List
           
            Thenode = Node(item)
            current = Node(item)
            root = Node(root)
            while current.next != None:
                current = current.next
            current.next = Thenode

            return root


        def reverseList(self, head):
            # Given the head of a Linked List, reverse it and return the head of the newly reversed Linked List
            node = Node(head)
            current = node
            while current.next != None:
                current = current.next

            reversed_list_head = current
            
            return reversed_list_head

        def print_as_list(self, head):
            # Given the head of Linked List, this function will convert it to a list while preserving the order of the Linked List
            # Return the list
            linked_list_as_list = []
            current = Node(head)
            while current.next != None:
                linked_list_as_list.append(current)

            return linked_list_as_list
```

Comment: Tú código debe ir en la pregunta y no en un enlace externo.

Comment: _gracias @Jacobo_

Comment: con respecto a la lógica no voy a opinar porque es subjetivo, en cuanto a la indentación si te fijas, las últimas dos funciones si están mal identadas, o sea no están a la altura de insert por ejemplo.

Comment: Cuando alguien plantea ejercicios de listas enlazadas en Python me queda claro que sabe C/C++, pero no Python. En Python la lista es un tipo básico, y se puede recorrer en ambos sentidos, ubicar cualquier elemento, insertar, eliminar, etc.

Answer (score 0):

El truco  esta en que cada elemento de la lista referencie al anterior y al posterior. Y tener un head y un root para cada lista...y posiblemente un flag(bool) que indique como se recorre la lista...

Para **INVERTIR** la lista bastaría con intercambiar los valores de head y root.he invertir el flag.

el codigo para insertar seria algo asi:

```
   def insert(self, root, item):
            Thenode = Node(item)
            if (root==None):
                self.head=Thenode
                return Thenode
            else:
               
                Thenode.next=None
                Thenode.prev=self.head
                self.head.next=Thenode
                self.head=Thenode
                
            
            return self.root
```

Y entonces invertir una *lista entrelazada* seria casi tan sencillo como esto;

```
def reverseList(self, head):
               
        self.head=self.root    
        self.root=head
        
        
        return self.head
```

Comment: Eso sería una lista doblemente enlazada, y a el le han planteado una lista enlazada simple

Comment: La definición de lista enlazada en el diccionario es una lista en la que cada elemento contiene datos y un puntero a uno o ambos elementos vecinos, eliminando así la necesidad de ordenar los elementos en la memoria.

Answer (score 0):

*No pretendo entrar en polémica*, pero creo que esto requiere una aclaración en general, no solo a @Francisco. Y como es algo extenso lo pongo como respuesta.

En la teoría de Tipos Abstractos de Datos (ADT en inglés), en el caso de las listas se distingue, entre otras: **Singly linked list** (listas enlazas simples), **Doubly linked list** (listas doblemente enlazadas) y **Circular linked list** (listas circulares). En cualquier caso con o sin limitación de tamaño (número de elementos totales).

[Linked Lists, Stacks and Queues using Python](https://python.plainenglish.io/linked-lists-stacks-and-queues-in-python-489147ac33cc)

[Data structures and Algorithms](https://www.programmingoneonone.com/p/data-structures-and-algorithms.html)

[linked list (lista encadenada)](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=linked%20list)
Estructura de datos, no necesariamente secuenciales en el almacenamiento, en el que cada elemento de información referencia a otro elemento de información, formándose de esta manera una cadena. El encadenamiento puede ser unidireccional al siguiente o al anterior, o bidireccional.

[doubly linked list (lista doblemente encadenada, - enlazada)](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=doubly%20linked%20list)
Lista encadenada en la que cada elemento hace referencia al anterior y al siguiente. De esta manera se puede recorrer la lista en ambas direcciones.

Por supuesto la implementación difiere, por eso en mi comentario apuntaba a que, si yo no lo había entendido mal, la propuesta del ejercicio hacía referencia a una lista enlazada simple. De hecho, en el código que nos pasó al principio, cada nodo solo contiene el dato y el puntero al siguiente elemento:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = data
        self.next = None
```

Mientras que en una lista doblemente encadenada, que sí permite el recorrido en ambos sentidos, el nodo debe disponer de un segundo enlace al elemento anterior.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.value = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
```